# setTimeout is working only once. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>    
        <script>
         function move(){
  var i =10;
  var demo = document.getElementById('demo3');
  demo.innerHTML = i;

  function run(){
    demo.innerHTML = ++i ;
  }
  var id = setTimeout(run,1000);
}

        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
         <div class="main-content">
             <div class="micro"><p id="demo3"></p></div>
             <input type="button" class="btn" id="start" onclick="move()" name="name" value="Start">
         </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

My code is not work properly. It should increase value of i continuously but it stops only after once. Please help.

Comment: Please try doing basic research before asking questions that can easily be solved in a web search

Answer (score 1):

because setTimeout is not the method you need, indeed it executes a code snippet once after a specified dalay, setInterval might do for your task:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Answer (score 1):

Change setTimeout to setInterval and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2ekucv8v/)

**setTimeout** runs the code once. You want to use the **setInterval** method to run the code repeatedly.

Comment: Please edit the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.